# How to change z-order by one increment in Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm very surprised there are only 2 options either to send the object to the top or to the bottom ? I just want to change by 1 increment.

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, you need to combine a call to [GetNextWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633509(VS.85).aspx) with [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx).

Edit: in the resource editor, you can set the Z-order with the Tab Order command.  After you've entered the Tab Order function, a number will appear by each control.  Control-click the control just before where you want to start ordering, then click each control after that to set it as the next in order.

Comment: Can't I do that Visually ? Because I need to copy a pile of Graphics buttons from one form to another and they are in Panel, I cannot select them all at once, so I need to copy one send move it to z-order - 1 etc.

Comment: But thanks for the functions, I will also need them in another context.

Comment: If my answer doesn't make any sense, it's because I'm using unmanaged C++.